# Create pdf of tableview all data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdf

I have create pdf of tableview all cells. but i have create the pdf it does not show all data of tableview & also when pdf page height set according to cells data. I dont know how to resolve this issue. I am using this code for create pdf.please help me.

```
  let _: NSData!
        do {
            let priorBounds = table_view.bounds
            let fittedSize = table_view.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, .infinity))
            table_view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height)
            let pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 800)
            let pdfData = NSMutableData()
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
            do {
                var pageOriginY = 0
                while pageOriginY < Int(fittedSize.height)  {
                    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
                    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                    do {
                        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!, 0, -CGFloat(pageOriginY))
                        table_view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                    }
                    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                    pageOriginY += Int(pdfPageBounds.size.height)
                }
            }
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
            table_view.bounds = priorBounds
            if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first {
                let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + (filename as String)
                debugPrint(documentsFileName)
                pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, atomically: true)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
func createPdfFromTableView()
{
    let priorBounds: CGRect = self.tblView.bounds
    let fittedSize: CGSize = self.tblView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: priorBounds.size.width, height: self.tblView.contentSize.height))
    self.tblView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: fittedSize.height)
    self.tblView.reloadData()
    let pdfPageBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittedSize.width, height: (fittedSize.height))
    let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
    self.tblView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let documentsFileName = documentDirectories! + "/" + "pdfName"
    pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    print(documentsFileName)
}
```

Comment: How would you share the created file using UIactivityviewcontroller?

Comment: its create single page pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One addition to Rajeskumar's answer below is as follows:

If your UITableView does not occupy the entire device screen with its original bounds, you might want to insert the following line:

```
self.tblview.bounds = priorBounds
```

after the render(in:) step.  Otherwise, the table will be drawn on the device in a manner in which it will cover more space that originally intended.

Comment: hi
where to add this above line?

Comment: After the render(in: step.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers did not work for creating PDF after tableview is scrolled at the bottom.
While reloading `tableview(reloadData())` after scrolling, correct PDF is not generated and removing, it won't generate PDF for unloaded items. 
So I have added extra condition and refactored as below:

```
extension UITableView {
    func convertToPDF() -> Data? {
        let priorBounds = self.bounds
        setBoundsForAllItems()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let pdfData = createPDF()
        self.bounds = priorBounds
        return pdfData.copy() as? Data
    }

    private func getContentFrame() -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.contentSize.width, height: self.contentSize.height)
    }

    private func createPDF() -> NSMutableData {
        let pdfPageBounds: CGRect = getContentFrame()
        let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return pdfData
    }

    private func setBoundsForAllItems() {
        if self.isEndOfTheScroll() {
            self.bounds = getContentFrame()
        } else {
            self.bounds = getContentFrame()
            self.reloadData()
        }
    }

    private func isEndOfTheScroll() -> Bool  {
        let contentYoffset = contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        return distanceFromBottom < frame.size.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create PDF of tableview using this way

```
       @IBAction func onClickBtnGeneratePDF(_ sender: Any) {
        if enterPDFNAME.text?.isEmpty() == true{
         Utility.showToast(message: "Please Enter PDF name")
        }else{
            self.viewOverlaySavePDF.isHidden = true
            Utility.showLoading()
            let pdfFilePath = tableview.exportAsPdfFromTable(pdfName: enterPDFNAME.text!)
            if pdfFilePath != nil {
                
                self.enterPDFNAME.text = ""
                Utility.showToast(message: "Your PDF file saved")
                Utility.hideLoading()
            }
            print(pdfFilePath)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

```
extension UITableView {
    
    // Export pdf from UITableView and save pdf in drectory and return pdf file path
    func exportAsPdfFromTable(pdfName:String) -> String {
        
        /*  let html = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b> <p>Generate PDF file from HTML in Swift</p>"
         let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)
         
         // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
         
         let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
         render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)
         
         // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
         
         let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
         let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
         
         render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
         render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")
         
         // 4. Create PDF context and draw
         
         let pdfData = NSMutableData()
         UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)
         
         for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {
         UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
         let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
         render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
         }
         
         UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
         */
        let originalBounds = self.bounds
        self.bounds = CGRect(x:originalBounds.origin.x, y: originalBounds.origin.y, width: self.contentSize.width, height: self.contentSize.height)
        let pdfPageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.contentSize.height)
        
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageFrame, nil)
        guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return "" }
        self.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        self.bounds = originalBounds
        // Save pdf data
        return self.saveTablePdf(data: pdfData,name:pdfName)
        
    }
    
    // Save pdf file in document directory
    func saveTablePdf(data: NSMutableData,name:String) -> String {
        
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("\(name).pdf")
        if data.write(to: pdfPath, atomically: true) {
            return pdfPath.path
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Only one solution for exporting all tableView items: **make snapshot of every part of tableview as an image -> merge them into an imageView -> render imageView to pdf**.

**NOTE: It's the same way with UIScrollView & UICollectionView**

```
func exportPDF() {
    // 1. estimate tableview contentsize
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.contentSize, false, 0)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
    tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    
    // 2. calculate number of part of tableview, loop and get snapshot
    let iterationCount = Int(ceil(tableView.contentSize.height / tableView.bounds.size.height))
    for i in 0..<iterationCount {
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(tableView.bounds.size.height) * i), animated: false)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    }
    
    // 3. merge and make UIImageView from snapshot
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    let pdfImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    
    //4. render imageView to PDF
    let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfImageView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfImageView.bounds, nil)
    pdfImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let documentsFileName = documentDirectories! + "/" + "MyPDF.pdf"
    pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    
    // 5. We have pdf file at documentsFileName
}
```