# how to create a table with rows and columns and convert it into pdf/excel/print (swift)

Tags: ios, excel, pdf

I would like to create rows and columns from the data given(concept is to create like a invoice with static columns and dynamic rows which can be edited). The columns are static but the rows are dynamic. The thing is we can do it in tableview, but the scenario is to save it as pdf/excel/print. As i referred i've got to know that there is a process of converting the data to a html template and then converting it as a pdf to print. Can anyone help me with this?

func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView)
    {

```
    let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height))
    tableView.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)
    let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
    var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0


    while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
        pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
    }


    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds
    var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDocc.pdf")


    pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)


    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: docURL)
    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x:20,y:20,width:view.frame.size.width-40, height:view.frame.size.height-40))
    webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"", baseURL: docURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

Here is the code i,ve used to convert the tableview data into a PDF.[image: converted tableview data] and [image: tableview that has the data]

Comment: Question is good but provide relevant code that you did try?

Comment: explain exactly what you did till now??/

Comment: It is possible that this question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647467/create-pdf-of-tableview-all-data  @Rajesh has an answer with a ```func createPdfFromTableView()```

Comment: As of now i found a way to convert data. That it converting the form into a html template. I exactly dont know what source of web or tool to convert to a template. I referred with (business Invoice bill gst tax and Gst invoice generator app),

Comment: I don't think I understand @Harish - Perhaps you could put some of your code in the question or in a gist, and we can try to help you.

Comment: @jessi check with the edited question.

Comment: you found any answer