# pdf from tableview with 100 cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdf

I am using below code to generate pdf from my tableview , but it generates pdf from visible cells only.
how to generate pdf from complete tableview

eg : Visible cells

```
cell1
cell2
.
.
.
.
.
cell10
```

non visible cell to current view

```
cell11
cell12
.
.
.
.
cell20
```

on generating pdf it only create pdf of visible cells 
I need to create all tableview cell1 to cell20 in pdf.

```
extension UITableView {

    // Export pdf from UITableView and save pdf in drectory and return pdf file path
    func exportAsPdfFromTable() -> String {

        let originalBounds = self.bounds
        self.bounds = CGRect(x:originalBounds.origin.x, y: originalBounds.origin.y, width: self.contentSize.width, height: self.contentSize.height)
        let pdfPageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.contentSize.height)

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageFrame, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageFrame, nil)
        guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return "" }
        self.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        self.bounds = originalBounds
        // Save pdf data
        return self.saveTablePdf(data: pdfData)

    }

    // Save pdf file in document directory
    func saveTablePdf(data: NSMutableData) -> String {

        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docDirectoryPath = paths[0]
        let pdfPath = docDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("tablePdf.pdf")
        if data.write(to: pdfPath, atomically: true) {
            return pdfPath.path
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

to use it

```
let pdfFilePath = self.tableView.exportAsPdfFromTable()
print(pdfFilePath)
```

Comment: can you post a picture of your table cells? Try to look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

Comment: also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581111/2149779

Comment: thanks for help, I have created html file and then use it to Create PDF finally works for me.

Comment: nice! post an answer to help others, if you can.

Comment: i need help @9to5ios, i want create pdf for all cell but i can't. help pls

Comment: @emredoğmaz I just create an HTML file and then convert it to pdf. for hack : just create html file with some specific tags, replace those tags with your own txt field entries (by checking if string contain that tag then replace it with new text field value)and then load that new html string to your web view  for display purpose and then create its pdf

Comment: can you share any source code with html? but i should not use PDFKit. my project ios 10.0